# How can I search the disabled AD account in the people picker of Sharepoint 2016?

Tags: 2016, people-picker

I'm using Sharepoint 2016. How can I search the diabled AD accounts in the people picker control? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is "by design". So theres only one workaround:

- create a custom claims provider for peoplepicker

Refer: [Plan for custom claims providers for People Picker in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg602072%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thank you for your information. But is there any other easy way to do that?

Comment: Any other way, like what? Only using OOTB or Designer or Coding